# Err using coroutine

Tags: lua

I'm not sure if I misunderstood the use of coroutine, but here is my code:

```
talk = coroutine.create(function ()
print("I am speaking within 60 seconds")
end)

time = coroutine.create(function ()
if coroutine.status(talk) == running then
for i = 60, 0, -1 do
print(i)
end
sleep(1)
else
coroutine.resume(talk)
end

end)
coroutine.resume(time)
```

All it print is I am speaking within 60 seconds, I was expecting it to say that within the countdown. How do I fix this?

Comment: `coroutine.status(talk) == "running"`

Answer (score 0):

```
talk = coroutine.create(function ()
print("I am speaking within 60 seconds")
coroutine.resume(time)
end)

time = coroutine.create(function ()
for i = 60, 0, -1 do
print(i)
coroutine.resume(talk)
end

end)

coroutine.resume(time)
```

Comment: You can't resume a non-suspended coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

```
talk = coroutine.create(function ()
    print("I am speaking within 60 seconds")
    coroutine.yield()
end)

time = coroutine.create(function ()
    for i = 60, 0, -1 do
        coroutine.resume(talk)
        print(i)
    end
end)

coroutine.resume(time)
```

Comment: Now you can resume the `talk` coroutine twice as opposed to once as in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling sleep but I don't see that function declared somewhere. Here's a modified version with sleep() implemented:

```
local function sleep(time)
    local sleep_until = os.time() + time
    repeat until os.time() >= sleep_until
end

local time, talk

talk = coroutine.create(function ()
    print("I am speaking in 60 seconds")
    coroutine.resume(time)
end)

time = coroutine.create(function ()
    while true do
        for i = 60, 0, -1 do
            print(i)
            sleep(1)
        end
        coroutine.resume(talk)
    end
end)

coroutine.resume(time)
```